# Mimicking random.sample() for non-uniform distributions

Tags: python, random, probability

I want to emulate the functionality of [random.sample()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) in python, but with a non-uniform (triangular, in this case) distribution of choices. Important for this is that a single item is not chosen twice (as described in the random.sample [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)). Here's what I have:

```
...

def tri_sample(population, k, mode=0):
    """
    Mimics the functionality of random.sample() but with a triangular
    distribution over the length of the sequence.

    Mode defaults to 0, which favors lower indices.
    """
    psize = len(population)
    if k > psize:
        raise ValueError("k must be less than the number of items in population.")
    if mode > psize:
        raise ValueError("mode must be less than the number of items in population.")
    indices_chosen = []
    sample = []
    for i in range(k):
        # This ensures unique selections
        while True:
            choice = math.floor(random.triangular(0, psize, mode))
            if choice not in indices_chosen:
                break
        indices_chosen.append(choice)
        sample.append(population[choice])
    return sample

...
```

My suspicion is that this is not an ideal way of preventing duplicate items being pulled. My first thought when designing this was to make a duplicate of `population` and `.pop()` the items as they're sampled to prevent choosing the same item twice, but I saw two problems with that:

1. If `population` is a list of objects, there could be some difficulty with duplicating the list while still ensuring that the items in `sample` point to the same objects in `population`.
2. Using `.pop()` on the population would change the size of the population, altering the distribution each time. Ideally, the distribution (not sure if I'm using the term correctly--the probability of each item being called) would be the same no matter what order the items are chosen in.

Is there a more efficient way of taking a non-uniform random sample from a population?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

The input to this function is as follows:

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

so you could specify the weight vector `p` to be your desired probability distribution, and also choose `replace=False`, so that samples would not be repeated.

Alternatively, you could sample directly from the triangular distribution using [numpy.random.triangular](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html). You can do that in a loop, and add the new result to the list only if it did not appear there before.